# In python, when and how can you use for and if statements without colons or indentation?

Tags: python, loops, generator, indentation

This question is specifically in regards to using generator statements and stems from this program from Udacity's design of computer programs course:

designed to solve this puzzle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zebra_Puzzle
this img may be more readable https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoRSZ.jpg

```
import itertools

def zebra_puzzle():

    houses = [first, _, middle, _,_] = [1,2,3,4,5]
    orderings = list(itertools.permutations(houses))
    return next((WATER, ZEBRA)

        for (red, green, ivory, yellow, blue) in orderings
        if im_right(green,ivory)

        for (Englishman, Spaniard, Ukranian, Japanese, Norwegian) in orderings
        if Englishman is red
        if first is Norwegian
        if nextto(Norwegian, blue)

        for (dog, snails, fox, horse, ZEBRA) in orderings
        if Spaniard is dog

        for (coffee, tea, milk, oj, WATER) in orderings
        if coffee is green
        if Ukranian is tea
        if middle is milk

        for (OldGold, Kools, Chesterfields, LuckyStrike, Parliaments) in orderings
        if OldGold is snails
        if Kools is yellow
        if nextto(Chesterfields, fox)
        if nextto(Kools,horse)
        if LuckyStrike is oj
        if Parliaments is Japanese
        )

def im_right(h1,h2):
    return h1-h2 == 1

def nextto(h1,h2):
    return abs(h1-h2) == 1

def main():
    zebra_puzzle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I keep running into problems in Project Euler where this would be useful but I end having to use normal nested loops.

also, is this question ok?

Comment: Ok what is the question? Are you getting any error? If so, please include the error. Are you getting unexpected output? If so, please include what you got and what you expected as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a generator expression syntax. the reason it works with multiple lines is because he wrapped it with () (normally it is written in 1 line of short statment to make obvious for statments shorter and cleaner)

you can see more details [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)

this syntax works as follows:

```
(one_value for one_value in my_list if one_value == 0)
```

the first one_value is what we want to do to each element in the list ( so we could do something like one_value+1 to return a list with all the values incremented by 1)

than there is a "for one_value" that way we call each element a name

"in my_list" - specify witch list we are iterating

"if one_value ==0" - a condition that will be applied for each value in the list

Comment: thank you, i didnt realize that was one long declaration of the generator

Answer (score 0):

`if` can be used, as in your example, in generator expressions and list comprehensions with `for` keyword.  See the relevant Python syntax BNF for ["`comp_if`"](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-comp_if) for the former case and ["`list_if`"](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-list_if) for the latter case.

You can also use `if` inline in expressions.  It is similar to C's tertiary operator `? :`.

E. g.

```
a = <expression_foo> if <some_condition> else <expression_bar>
```

In this statement, the condition `<some_condition>` gets evaluated, and determines which expression's value gets assigned to `a`.